# How to change font size of species labels in vegan's biplot() function

Tags: r, vegan, biplot

I am trying to create a series of publishable biplots of a PCA on insect abundance in different strata (tree canopy and understory) of forests. I am doing this using the rda() function. To create the plot, I am using vegan's `biplot()` function and do a couple of modifications to it:

```
Family=read.table("Family2.txt", header=T)
strata=read.table("Strata.txt", header=T)

family.pca=rda(Family)

with(strata, levels(Strata))

biplot(family.pca, type=c("text", "none"), col=c("black", "black"), xlab="", 
ylab="")
title(xlab="PC1 (86.8%)", ylab="PC2 (9.7%)", mgp=c(2.2, 2.2, 0))
points=c(16, 1)
colour=c("black", "black")
with(strata, points(family.pca, display = "sites", col = colour, pch = 
points))
with(strata, legend("topright", legend = levels(Strata), bty = "n", col = 
colour, pch = points, pt.bg = points))
```

The result is quite nice:

[image]

But because I will join several biplots to a bigger graph, the labels for the families (usually called 'species labels') are too small. I tried to change them using `cex=1.5` in `biplot()`, but it seems to get overwritten by the defaults of the function. When I create an empty biplot frame by setting `type=c("none", "none")`, I can add bigger species labels using the `text()` function, e.g.

```
text(family.pca, display = "species", cex = 1.0, col = "black")
```

but then I don't know how to add the arrows to the plot (I would really like to have the arrows in there...).

Does anybody know of a solution for this case? Answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend going to `?biplot`   you should see an explanation for the argument `cex` in the documentation. That should help you as it related to the labels of the plot and the size of these labels.

Comment: This answer is not very helpful for the OP. I won't downvote, but recommend to take the time to make the answer more helpful...Better to leave such "answers" as comments.

Comment: To add to this, it's not that straight forward: the cex argument for biplot seems to work in some instances such as prcomp (e.g. `biplot(prcomp(state.x77), cex=c(0.5,0.75))`) but doesn't work with others such as rda that @Lukas was using (e.g. `biplot(prcomp(state.x77), cex=c(0.5,0.75))`). Agree with @Mikko here, it'd be more useful to have a reproducible answer than recommending solutions that don't work. If I find a clear answer I'll update seperately.